# can't resolve phpMyAdmin permissions for config.inc.php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've tried sudo chmod 705 config.inc.php in the phpMyAdmin folder, and I still get Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!

I tried 644 and 755, but I still get the same error. I tried chmoding the entire phpMyAdmin folder. I even tried one of the other suggestions here on Stack Overflow by commenting out the check permissions function in /phpmyadmin/libraries/Config.class.php. No go.

I haven't done anything with PHP in months, but it worked at one point. What could have changed, and what can I do?

Comment: Unsure why 705 didn't work. Try 600

Comment: checkout this for permission of config.inc.php https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install#With_setup_script

Answer (score 0):

If you get a permission denied from http server

> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

then it may be because of this

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

change it to

```
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```